# How to fetch without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous

Okay so, I recently started learning about async JS and APIs and fetch and am just creating a small project for practice and I want to add 2 more features to it

1. I want to add a button on which when clicked without refreshing the page,   gives us a new GIF.
2. A search bar for the GIF we can find using that bar.

Here is my code:

```html
<body>
  <img src="#" />
  <button>New Giffy</button>
  <script>
    const img = document.querySelector('img');
    const btn = document.querySelector('button');

    fetch(
        `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/translate?api_key=pH9WHztAm5Yt9v5VAziRzXhOBvblWf6m&s=akatsuki`, {
          mode: 'cors'
        }
      )
      .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
      })
      .then((response) => {
        img.src = response.data.images.original.url;
      });
  </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can provide `onClick` on button which will call the function defined in below code or refer [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Wahab896/cpLtw3oz/12/)

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" placeholder="search here..." id="searchField" value="akatsuki">
  <button onClick="onGifClick()">New Giffy</button><br>
  <img src="#" />
  <script>
    function onGifClick() {
      const search = document.querySelector('#searchField');
      const img = document.querySelector('img');
      const btn = document.querySelector('button');
      debugger;
      fetch(
          `https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/translate?api_key=pH9WHztAm5Yt9v5VAziRzXhOBvblWf6m&s=` + search.value, {
            mode: 'cors'
          }
        )
        .then((response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .then((response) => {
          img.src = response.data.images.original.url;
        });
    }
    onGifClick();
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: But this won't provide the gif as soon as the page loads

Comment: Just call the method once after defining it (Added the change and updated the fiddle)

Comment: thanks it helped a lot but i still need to figure out how can i add a search bar where i can have my desired gifs, can u please help me out with it:)

Comment: @DevChaudhary I have updated my code with a search field as a simple text field and taking the text field value in  fetch url. This is the simplest way to achieve your use case.

Comment: @wahabmemon i strongly appreciate your help and it worked and easy to understand thanks for your time:)

Comment: @wahabmemon sorry am new to stackoverflow can you demonstrate me how to mark this answer?

Comment: On the left side of my answer, there are 2 arrows for upvote and downvote of answers. And if answer is correct then there is a ✔ (check) mark below the arrows. Just press that mark, it turns green and answer gets accepted.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight forward thing. But I will help you.

```html
 <body>
    <img src="#" />
    <button onclick="newGif()">New Giffy</button>
    <script>
      const img = document.querySelector('img');
      const btn = document.querySelector('button');
      function newGif(){
        fetch(`https://api.giphy.com/v1/gifs/translate?api_key=pH9WHztAm5Yt9v5VAziRzXhOBvblWf6m&s=akatsuki`,{mode:'cors'})
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((response) => {
          img.src = response.data.images.original.url;
        });
      }
      newGif() //This is so a new gif is loaded as soon as the page loads
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: thanks it helped a lot but i still need to figure out how can i add a search bar where i can have my desired gifs, can u please help me out with it:)